# why the hide() is not hiding the element?

Tags: jquery, css, form-submit

I have a radio button that if it is selected, I would need to check if the file is uploaded.

If the 'Other' radio button is chosen, the red message shows which is correct.

But if it doesn't show, also, still shows the same message but in black.

I want it to not show the message in black (not show the message at all), if 'Other' is not selected. I understand my current code is not complete.

Also, I have written it currently expecting the 'submit' button being opaque until the file is upload in case 'other' is chosen but is not reacting to it and is not disabled.

```
$("#otherradiobutton").on('click', function () {

    let hasError = false;
    let color = 'red';

    if ($("annotatedsamplefile").val() == null){
        alert('null');
        $('#emptysamplefileerror').show();
        $('#emptysamplefileerror').css('color', color);
        hasError = true;
    }
    else {
        $('#emptysamplefileerror').hide();
    }


    $('button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', hasError);

})
```

and

```
<input type="file" name="annotatedsamplefile" id="annotatedsamplefile" accept=".xlsx, .xls, .csv">
<span id="emptysamplefileerror"><b>Please upload a sample annotated file if you chose <b>Other</b> </b></span>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check the computed CSS of `$('#emptysamplefileerror')` element in your browser's Developer Console?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean or how I check it. @Raptor

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish. Since this code is in the click handler for #otherradiobutton, it won't run unless that button is clicked

Comment: @Raptor please check the screenshot I added.

Comment: Where is your other radio button?? Generally you should use change event on radio and selects.

Comment: Please check you added jquery properly before your code.

Answer (score 1):

using `style="display:none;` in below worked.

```
<span id="emptysamplefileerror" style="display:none;">Please upload a sample annotated file if you chose <b>Other</b></span>
```

Comment: Of course it will work. However, your original code is to hide the element via a button click on `$("#otherradiobutton")`, while what you're now doing is just to hide via inline CSS, which is different.